# Why is there a big difference between the time spent inside the loop and the time spent outside the loop?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
MatrixXi Eigen_BF::find_TopK(const Eigen::Ref<const MatrixXf> &mat, int topK){

    PARAM_MIPS_TOP_K = topK;
    PARAM_QUERY_Q = mat.cols();
    MATRIX_Q = mat;


    MatrixXi matTopK = MatrixXi::Zero(PARAM_MIPS_TOP_K, PARAM_QUERY_Q);

    auto startTime = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    float loopin_time, loopout_time = 0.0;
    for (int q = 0; q < PARAM_QUERY_Q ; ++q){

        auto out_startTime = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        priority_queue< IFPair, vector<IFPair>, greater<IFPair> > minQueTopK;

        for (int n = 0; n < PARAM_DATA_N; n++){

            auto in_startTime = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            float fValue = MATRIX_Q.col(q).dot(MATRIX_X.col(n));

            // Insert into minQueue
            if ((int)minQueTopK.size() < PARAM_MIPS_TOP_K)
                minQueTopK.push(IFPair(n, fValue));
            else
            {
                // Insert into minQueue
                if (fValue > minQueTopK.top().m_fValue)
                {
                minQueTopK.pop();
                minQueTopK.push(IFPair(n, fValue));
                }
            }
            auto in_durTime = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - in_startTime);
            loopin_time += (float)in_durTime.count() * 1e-3;

        }
            auto out_durTime = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - out_startTime);
            loopout_time += (float)out_durTime.count() * 1e-3;

        for (int n = PARAM_MIPS_TOP_K - 1; n >= 0; --n)
        {
            // Get point index
            matTopK.col(q)(n) = minQueTopK.top().m_iIndex;
            minQueTopK.pop();
        }

    }

    auto durTime = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - startTime);

    cout << "Loop in Time : "<< loopin_time << endl;
    cout << "Loop out Time : "<< loopout_time << endl;
    cout << "TopK Time : "<< (float)durTime.count() * 1e-3 << endl;
    return matTopK;
}
```

In this code I counted the time inside the loop, the time outside the loop and the total time. It turns out that loop out time and total time are approximate, but loop in time and loop out time are very different. My intuition is that the loop in time should be similar to the loop out time, but this is not the case. Can anyone help me to explain the reason for this? Thank you.

ps:
When PARAM_MIPS_TOP_K = 10, PARAM_QUERY_Q = 1000, PARAM_DATA_N = 60000
without any optimization like -O3, in Debug mode
the result is loop in time : 61014ms / loop out time : 119789ms / total time : 120950ms

Comment: On a totally unrelated note, there's almost never a need to use `float` in your programs. Use `double`.

Comment: The outer loop time includes 120,000 calls to fetch the high-resolution clock.  Those calls are not free.  Hard to imagine 5ms each, though.

Comment: This program exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing uninitialized variable `loopin_time`

Comment: Thank you for your comments. And I also tried not recording the inner loop time, and then the outer loop time decreases a little, but not significantly.

Comment: loopin_time must be in initialized to 0.0 as well !

Comment: Thank you , I have also initialized loopin_time = 0.0. But the difference is not change.

Answer (score 0):

```
MatrixXi Eigen_BF::find_TopK(const Eigen::Ref<const MatrixXf> &mat, int topK){



    PARAM_MIPS_TOP_K = topK;
    PARAM_QUERY_Q = mat.cols();
    MATRIX_Q = mat;


    MatrixXi matTopK = MatrixXi::Zero(PARAM_MIPS_TOP_K, PARAM_QUERY_Q);

    auto startTime = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    double loopin_time = 0.0;
    double loopout_time = 0.0;
    for (int q = 0; q < PARAM_QUERY_Q ; ++q){

        auto out_startTime = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        priority_queue< IFPair, vector<IFPair>, greater<IFPair> > minQueTopK;

        for (int n = 0; n < PARAM_DATA_N; n++){

            auto in_startTime = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            double fValue = MATRIX_Q.col(q).dot(MATRIX_X.col(n));

            // Insert into minQueue
            if ((int)minQueTopK.size() < PARAM_MIPS_TOP_K)
                minQueTopK.push(IFPair(n, fValue));
            else
            {
                // Insert into minQueue
                if (fValue > minQueTopK.top().m_fValue)
                {
                minQueTopK.pop();
                minQueTopK.push(IFPair(n, fValue));
                }
            }
            auto in_durTime = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - in_startTime);
            loopin_time += (double)in_durTime.count() * 1e-3;

        }
        auto out_durTime = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - out_startTime);
        loopout_time += (double)out_durTime.count() * 1e-3;

        for (int n = PARAM_MIPS_TOP_K - 1; n >= 0; --n)
        {
            // Get point index
            matTopK.col(q)(n) = minQueTopK.top().m_iIndex;
            minQueTopK.pop();
        }

    }

    auto durTime = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - startTime);

    cout << "Loop in Time : "<< loopin_time << endl;
    cout << "Loop out Time : "<< loopout_time << endl;
    cout << "TopK Time : "<< (double)durTime.count() * 1e-3 << endl;
    return matTopK;
}
```

I modified the code. But the difference between loopin time and loopout time is still large.

For now, loop in time : 77246ms / loop out time : 126170ms / total time : 126176ms